# Deformation and Homomorphism

Tags: general-topology

In Armstrong's topology book 1st chapter,it is written that  we can deform polyhedron of Euler characteristic 2 to sphere by stretching and bending.This is an example of topological equivalence.In formal terms ,we define the homomorphism to be continuous bijection with continuous inverse.I was wondering how the definition of a homomorphism will capture the idea of deformation of one structure into other in Euclidean space.

Comment: Picture it in your head. If you deform a space, points in the old space correspond to points in the new space. If you did this continuously, this correspondence ought to be continuous. If you want this to be an equivalence, it ought to be invertible, and its inverse also continuous. If you want, there is an equivalent definition of continuous: a bijection $X\to Y$ which induces a bijection $\tau_X\to\tau_Y$ (where $\tau_X,\tau_Y$ are the topologies, i.e. there is also a correspondence between open sets).